# NullReferenceException from adding a Cookie to a CookieCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I get a nullreference exception at the cookiecontainer.add(OC);

I dont know what i was doing wrong, as i was following an example from: [Sending cookies using HttpCookieCollection and CookieContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214387/sending-cookies-using-httpcookiecollection-and-cookiecontainer/1214428#comment17793512_1214428) and I more or less was following it perfectly.  The error occurs for both INDEX and KEY referencing to the cookie.

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(URI);
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        HttpCookieCollection cookieJar = Request.Cookies;
        //foreach (string cookieString in Request.Cookies)
        for(int i = 0; i < cookieJar.Count; i++)
        {
            System.Web.HttpCookie cookie = cookieJar.Get(i);
            Cookie oC = new Cookie();
            oC.Domain = Request.Url.Host;
            oC.Expires = cookie.Expires;
            oC.Name = cookie.Name;
            oC.Path = cookie.Path;
            oC.Secure = cookie.Secure;
            oC.Value = cookie.Value;

            request.CookieContainer.Add(oC);
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer.Add(oC);
```

`A CookieContainer is null by default. You must assign a CookieContainer object to the property to have cookies returned in the Cookies property of the HttpWebResponse returned by the GetResponse method.`-***MSDN***

Comment: Thanks a lot.  For some reason, i was just thinking it an empty container, but now i know different.